# Replace multiple space with single space, Remove " and leading 0 using APACHE PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Need help with PIG

```
A = load 'input.txt' as (line:chararray);
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE(($0, '\\s+', ' ')
```

Need help on the last line to Replace multiple space with single space, Remove `"` (Quotes) and leading `00` using APACHE PIG

Note:- Approach should NOT be field specific as there are more than 70 fields, 
 Basically, expecting help with REPLACE or STRSTRING OR REGEX function which can perfomr mentioned operations on a line.

*Input.txt*

```
00595, ab 000cdef      california "state,   00USA
00733, 0ds ds "ARIZONA 00state, USA
```

*Expected Output*

```
595, ab cdef califormia state, USA
733, ds ds ARIZONA state, USA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` function in Pig to do the cleaning and loading as INT will remove the leading zeros from the number.

```
A = LOAD '/usr/pigfiles/pigo.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (value: INT, state: chararray, country: chararray);  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE value,REPLACE(REPLACE(state,'  ', ' ' ),'\\"',''),  country; 
DUMP B;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for response Abhi.  But there are almost 70 fields and I cannot pass field name, so AS clause in Pigstorage cannot be used and thats whey I relied  upon (line:chararray). Also, I am not good with REGEX and need help in REGEX for mentioned conditions - multiple space with single space, Remove " (Quotes) and leading 00. Also, IS nested REPLACE allowed?

Comment: Its better to write a Pig UDF which does the cleaning for you by splitting the line based on the separator. Its not necessary to pass a schema, you can achieve this by using column position $0, $1.. . Nested Replace is allowded.

Comment: just a thought - I will run the whole data through 1 script which reads whole line as 1 field (1 field per record), replace multiple spaces with single, removing quotes and leading 00 (you need to pass that 1 field through the replace), will dump output in intermediate file and then will read the data through 2nd script which reads comma separated fields as separate fields on line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested REPLACE function within same loop. You have to do a series of operation on your data to get your desired result.

Try below code on your data. it is working well on sample you provided.

`*a = LOAD 'ip.txt' USINGTextLoader();*`

`*b = FOREACH a GENERATE REPLACE($0,'\\s+',' ');*`

`*c = FOREACH b GENERATE REPLACE($0,'"','');*`

`*d = FOREACH c GENERATE REPLACE($0,'\\s+0+',' ');*`

Comment: It doesnt handle interim 0, please refer to the edited input                                                                                                                                    Input                                                                                                                     00595, ab 0000cdef california state, 0USA

00733,   0ds 00ds 0ARIZONA state, USA

Comment: Well in that case you can use '\\s+0+' to identify interim zeros and then simply replace it with a space. Check above